How to decompile corrupted .NET assembly that is missing CLI header but the part of source code is intact?
I have a corrupted .NET assembly that I want to reverse engineer but every .NET decompiler gives me an error because the end of file which contains CLI header is missing while the rest of file is intact. Can I somehow get IL code out of it even though the header is missing?
I tried ILSpy, Dotpeek, ildasm - nothing worked.
Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9A4itH0QRJPd4xgsNQiQ6TE_fM0-f9v/view?usp=drive_link
It may be missing some code and some .xaml files, obviously it is missing the CLI header, which is always given at the very end of the assembly.
Error message from ILSpy:
// This file does not contain a managed assembly.

System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid metadata section span.
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpyX.LoadedAssembly.LoadAsync(Task`1 streamTask) in /_/ICSharpCode.ILSpyX/LoadedAssembly.cs:line 387
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TreeNodes.AssemblyTreeNode.Decompile(Language language, ITextOutput output, DecompilationOptions options)

I've been able to get the contents of an included .xaml file just by browsing the assembly with a text editor:
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="1000" Height="187" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="r_drive">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="car">

But I have no idea how to get the intermediate language source code in a human-readable form from the assembly.

Why silverlight tag? The latter content looks like xaml-resource (could be wpf?), which could be easily visible with hex-editor, but extracting IL is another story. I would be very surprized if you can cut half of assembly and still be able to decompile the other half like nothing is lost.

I tagged it as "silverlight" because I posess other uncorrupted silverlight assembly that dynamically loads the assembly I'm trying to recover from a server when user requests it as a .xap file. The ease with which I was able to find out the contents of the xaml gave me hope that the IL could also be extracted. It is also possible that this xaml is the last element in the contents of the file, but I don’t know, since the assembly ends  right at the xaml file, xaml is incomplete. In this case, only the header is missing.
